# MATLAB field access with inheritance modifying all instances?

Tags: matlab, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to develop a data structure for a mesh using the MATLAB OOP functionalities. Long story short, I'm modifying a field from an instance that inherits from the same base class as another instance, and both instances are being modified, as if the field was declared static!

I have this code inside an abstract base class (m_element) in MATLAB:

```
properties(Access = protected)
    nodes = containers.Map('KeyType','int64', 'ValueType', 'any');
    faces = containers.Map('KeyType','int64', 'ValueType', 'any');
end
```

These field represent the connectivity of each element. For example, which nodes are neighbors of the n'th node, or which faces are adjacent to the n'th node.

I also have two other classes: m_face and m_node, each one inheriting from m_element.
m_node is very simple:

```
classdef m_node < m_element
    properties
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    end

    methods
        function node = m_node(gmsh_id, x, y, z)
            node = node@m_element(gmsh_id);

            node.x = x;
            node.y = y;
            node.z = z;
        end
    end
end
```

But when it comes to m_face, I'm facing an issue. Here's the constructor, where the problem is arising:

```
function face = m_face(varargin)

    face = face@m_element(varargin{1});


    for k = 2:nargin
        nod = varargin{k};


        if(~isa(nod, 'm_node'))
            error('Algum dos argumentos não é um node!');
        elseif (~isvalid(nod))
            error('Algum dos argumentos não é válido!');
        else

            face.nodes(nod.gmsh_id) = nod;

            nod.faces(face.gmsh_id) = face;
        end

    end
end
```

The m_face constructor expects the face ID to come as the first argument, and the rest should be the nodes that forms the face. The line `face.nodes(nod.gmsh_id) = nod;` seems to be causing my problem. I have a m_mesh class which shall hold every node and face:

```
classdef m_mesh < handle
    properties(SetAccess = private)
        nodes = containers.Map('KeyType','int64', 'ValueType', 'any');
        faces = containers.Map('KeyType','int64', 'ValueType', 'any');
    end

    methods

        function theMesh = m_mesh(msh)
            for idx = 1:numel(msh.POS(:,1))
                n = msh.POS(idx,:);
                theMesh.nodes(idx) = m_node(idx, n(1), n(2), n(3));
            end

            for idx = 1:numel(msh.TRIANGLES(:,1))
                ele = msh.TRIANGLES(idx,:);
                nod(1) = theMesh.nodes(ele(1));
                nod(2) = theMesh.nodes(ele(2));
                nod(3) = theMesh.nodes(ele(3));

                theMesh.faces(idx) = m_face(idx, nod(1), nod(2), nod(3));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The `msh` argument to the constructor holds the nodes spatial positions, and also the nodes that composes each face (which in this case are triangles).

Here's what I get when I build the mesh:

```
>> mesh = m_mesh(m)

mesh = 

m_mesh with properties:

nodes: [5x1 containers.Map]
edges: [0x1 containers.Map]
faces: [4x1 containers.Map]

>> nod = mesh.nodes.values();
>> nod{1}.i_nodes

ans = 

[1x1 m_node]    [1x1 m_node]    [1x1 m_node]    [1x1 m_node]    [1x1 m_node]
```

The i_nodes returns the instance map values. Now, how's that possible? Why does my first (and all the others!) node have FIVE adjacent nodes, if I haven't set this yet? Why should MATLAB change an non-static field for all instances and all subclasses when I access this field from a random instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise your `nodes` and `faces` properties in the constructor, not as a default property value.

So what's going on here? The first thing to note is that `containers.Map` is a `handle` class.

Normal variables in MATLAB have *value* behaviour:

```
>> a = 1;
>> b = a;
>> a = 2;
>> b
b =
     1
```

Note that `b` has not changed when you changed `a` - it is a copy of `a`, and `a` and `b` are *value* variables that have *pass-by-value* behaviour.

Some other variables have *handle* behaviour:

```
>> a = figure;
>> b = a;
>> get(a, 'Name')
ans =
     ''
>> get(b, 'Name')
ans =
     ''
>> set(a, 'Name', 'hello')
>> get(b, 'Name')
ans =
hello
```

Note that `b` has changed when you changed `a` - it is a reference to `a`, and `a` and `b` are *handle* variables that have *pass-by-reference* behaviour.

`containers.Map` variables are handle variables.

The second thing to note is that property default values are evaluated *once*, at the first time the class is instantiated. (If you clear the class definition with `clear classes`, it will be evaluated again subsequently when you next instantiate it). They are *not* evaluated every time you create an object.

So what's happening is that the first time you create an object, the class is instantiated, the `containers.Map` is evaluated, and each object after that is getting the *same* `containers.Map` as its property. Since it's a handle variable, changes that you then make to the property in one object are referenced in the properties of others.

You don't want that: instead, you should initialise the values in the class constructor. Then it will get evaluated separately each time you construct an object, and each will get a separate one.

This behaviour (i.e., when you have handle variables as property defaults) can be confusing, but I think it's the right behaviour - it is documented, although I think it could be more clearly signposted. Here's an [article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/handle-object-as-default-class-property-value) where the topic is discussed - in the comments, the issue is debated between the author, myself, and a MathWorks developer responsible for OO syntax and design.

Comment: Dude! Thanks! This was driving me insane.I will read the article for sure.

Comment: You see, I was used to programming in C++, Java, and other OO languages before. So this behavior didn't occur to me, even tho I was used to the value / handle duality. Now I understand.