# Faster alternative to Containers.map?

Tags: matlab, oop, containers

This question is related to: [Matlab: dynamically storing objects, alternatives to containers.Map class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635951/matlab-dynamically-storing-objects-alternatives-to-containers-map-class)

I'm building a data structure that needs to have key-value functionality, where the key is an int and the value is an object. And also needs to be able to dinamically add elements to this key-value map.

So, Containers.map would a good option, but it is extremely slow (I have measured retrieval of values on a map of ~450 elements to be around 0.1s on my Linux machine). That's really strange, as I thought that they would implement this class as a hashmap or something like that.

I need something a lot faster. I'm thinking on implementing myself a balanced binary search tree or something like that, but I don't know if this kind if dynamic recursive object would be fast on MATLAB (probably not).

Is it possible to bind std::map into my application, or something else, that is faster than Containers.map?

Edit, clarifications and code sample:
I'm running this on a Matlab 2015a on linux. Here's a reproduction of the bad performance. In this program, the performance is not as bad because on my program I have a much more complex class hierarchy which generates a lot of overhead (the simple act of having a for to iterate for each element of the map and simply retrieve it takes almost 1 minute when there was ~450 elements). Here, I created a very simple graph class to illustrate the problem. pastebin.com/TvyzJxgK

Comment: From MATLAB you usually have access to the application-bundled JVM, so you could use any implementation of java.util.Map like java.util.HashMap. Do take into account that numeric keys will be interpreted as Double by default, though.

Comment: I could not find a way to use a MATLAB class as a value of a java.util.HashMap.

Comment: Per [the Matlab docs](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-a-java-method.html), I don't think you can pass a Matlab object to Java, but there might be some way around the "unsupported" in that table.

Comment: By the way, now that you've said that you're using Matlab classes as either keys or values, are you sure that the bad performance of cointainers.Map is not due to the general slowness of Matlab OOP calling, e.g. your class' equality comparison when used as a key?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the bad performance, please share the benchmark with us. It might indicate the problem.

Comment: ... and of course indicate which `version` of Matlab you're using.

Comment: Javier, the classes are being used as value only. The keys are integer.

Comment: I'm running this on a Matlab 2015a on linux. Daniel, here's a reproduction of the bad performance. In this program, the performance is not as bad because on my program I have a much more complex class hierarchy which generates a lot of overhead (the simple act of having a for to iterate for each element of the map and simply retrieve it takes almost 1 minute when there was ~450 elements). Here, I created a very simple graph class to illustrate the problem. http://pastebin.com/TvyzJxgK

Comment: Please use the @ symbol to address other users, e.g., @Daniel, or they may never see your comment. You should update your question rather than posting such details in a comment. And you should also provide the code you use to bench mark this. Lastly, why does your constructor use `containers.Map` too?

Comment: @horchler, thanks for the tips. I have benchmarked the code I've posted using the "Run and Time" (a.k.a. profiler) functionality of Matlab. The constructor needs to create the containers.Map due to the nature of Matlab's class initialization. Had I put it on the properties section being initialized there, the containers.Map inherits from handle, and therefore, every class instance of my_class would point to the same containers.Map. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091354/matlab-field-access-with-inheritance-modifying-all-instances/32092118#32092118.

Comment: @JavierMartín Please check my comment above, if you haven't already.